# Homebrew update on OS-X: do we still need the/usr/local/Cellar directory?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Yesterday I ran brew update and after migrating the repository, it reported that:

> ==> Migrated HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY to /usr/local/Homebrew!
>   Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you can
>   return /usr/local to its default ownership with:
>
> sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local

This issue of ownership is discussed further here: [at Apple Stack.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/how-does-homebrew-no-longer-need-ownership-of-usr-local)

But after this update do we still need the Homebrew Cellar directory and all of its associated subfolders located here:

> /usr/local/Cellar

As we know, the libraries installed at */usr/local/Cellar* are symlinked to */usr/local/lib*, but it isn't clear whether or not we still need the Cellar directory and files.

After the update, Homebrew was apparently migrated to this location:

> /usr/local/Homebrew

And there are a number of new subdirectories starting here:

> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew

where there are Ruby scripts for each of the formula.  But it wasn't obvious to me that this new file structure makes */usr/local/Cellar* obsolete.

I couldn't find a place to post the question here: [Homebrew/brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew) so I sent the question to *homebrew-discuss@googlegroups.com* and got back the message that: *"...writing to let you know that the group you tried to contact (homebrew-discuss) may not exist..."*

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, keep the other directories. It just means that `/usr/local` *on it's own* doesn't need to be owned by the ordinary user, although the lower directories still end up owned by the user (e.g. `/usr/local/Homebrew`)